# Finding the index of lowest value, my assertion is failing

Tags: javascript, arrays, selection-sort

The assignment was:

> Finish writing the function `indexOfMinimum`, which takes an array and a number `startIndex`, and returns the index of the smallest value that occurs with index `startIndex` or greater. If this smallest value occurs more than once in this range, then return the index of the leftmost occurrence within this range.

Here's my attempt to complete it

```
var indexOfMinimum = function(array, startIndex) {
    // Set initial values for minValue and minIndex,
    // based on the leftmost entry in the subarray:  
    var minValue = array[startIndex];
    var minIndex = startIndex;
    for (var i = minIndex + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[startIndex]) {
            minIndex = i;
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    }

    // Loop over items starting with startIndex, 
    // updating minValue and minIndex as needed:

    return minIndex;
};

var array = [18, 6, 66, 44, 9, 22, 14];
var index = indexOfMinimum(array, 2);

//  For the test array [18, 6, 66, 44, 9, 22, 14], 
//  the value 9 is the smallest of [..66, 44, 9, 22, 14]
//  Since 9 is at index 4 in the original array, 
//  "index" has value 4
println("The index of the minimum value of the subarray starting at index 2 is " + index + ".");
Program.assertEqual(index, 4);
```

The assertion at the end is failing. According to my logic it returns the 4 index but I think it doesn`t work correctly. Why not?

Comment: The "insertion statement"? Which statement is that?

Comment: Program.assertEqual(index, 4); this one

Comment: By far the best way to figure out why something like this isn't working is to use the debugger built into your browser or IDE. Set a breakpoint on the first statement in your function, run the code, and the debugger will stop at that breakpoint. Then you can step through and watch your logic and inspect your variables as you go. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill; it's basically the first thing you should learn after successfully writing "Hello, world". Happy coding!

Comment: How to use debugger, I don`t know it

Comment: @MuhammadHamza: A search will find you lots of useful information. For Chrome's debugger: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: (Don't let the downvote bother you. You asked a reasonably clear question and included the code that you were having trouble with.)

Comment: Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: I have a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison

```
if(array[i]<array[startIndex])
```

is wrong. You should be comparing

```
if(array[i]<minValue)
```

...since you want to find out if `array[i]` is less than the minimum value you've found so far, not less than the first value you looked at.

With that change, it works:

```js
var indexOfMinimum = function(array, startIndex) {
// Set initial values for minValue and minIndex,
// based on the leftmost entry in the subarray:  
var minValue = array[startIndex];
var minIndex = startIndex;
for(var i = minIndex + 1 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
    if(array[i]<minValue)
    {
        minIndex = i;
        minValue = array[i];
    }
}

// Loop over items starting with startIndex, 
// updating minValue and minIndex as needed:

return minIndex;
}; 

var array = [18, 6, 66, 44, 9, 22, 14];   
var index = indexOfMinimum(array, 2);

//  For the test array [18, 6, 66, 44, 9, 22, 14], 
//  the value 9 is the smallest of [..66, 44, 9, 22, 14]
//  Since 9 is at index 4 in the original array, 
//  "index" has value 4
console.log("The index of the minimum value of the subarray starting at index 2 is " + index + "."  );
```

---

*(Spaces aren't evil, btw.)*